# Python Recursion for finding subsets of a string given as input

Tags: python, string, recursion

I am trying so find out the subsets of a string using recursion method and have applied this code but I am not getting my desired output.

```
list1=[]

def reverse_way(stringelement,pos,choice):

    if(pos==len(stringelement)):
        return
    for item in stringelement:
        x=item+choice
        list1.append(x)
    
    reverse_way(stringelement,pos+1,stringelement[pos])

reverse_way("abc",0,"")
list1
```

The output should be `["a","b","c","ab","bc","ac","abc",""]`

But I am getting `['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'ba', 'ca', 'ab', 'bb', 'cb']`.

Please can anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of modifying a global list, it is better to return the results back to the caller.

To get subsets, remember that there are two choices you can make at each index: either take this element or not. The base case is when we reach the end of the string, where we return the string we have built up so far. With that in mind, we get the following straightforward implementation of this idea:

```py
def reverse_way(stringelement, pos, choice):
    if pos == len(stringelement):
        return [choice]
    return reverse_way(stringelement, pos + 1, choice) + 
           reverse_way(stringelement, pos + 1, choice + stringelement[pos])
```

This can also be done with `itertools.combinations`:

```py
from itertools import combinations
def subsets(s):
    return [''.join(c) for i in range(0, len(s) + 1) for c in combinations(s, i)]
```